# Most efficient way to merge collections preserving order?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 3 channels:

```
byte[] Red;
byte[] Green;
byte[] Blue;
```

I need to copy all the values from them into a `byte[Red.Length+Green.Length+Blue.Length] PA`, so that:

```
PA[0] = Red[0];
PA[1] = Green[0];
PA[2] = Blue[0];
PA[3] = Red[1];
/// and so on
```

Here is an example with the above arrays:

```
byte[] Red = new byte[255];
byte[] Green = new byte[255];
byte[] Blue = new byte[255];
byte[] PA = new byte[Red.Length + Green.Length + Blue.Length];
for (int i = 0; i != 255; ++i)
{
    PA[i*3 + 0] = Red[i];
    PA[i*3 + 1] = Green[i];
    PA[i*3 + 2] = Blue[i];
}
```

I'm assuming that the collections to be merged are of equal sizes and that they do have some order amongst themselves e.g. `[0] = Red`, `[1]=Green`, etc. that has to be preserved for the items in the "merged" collection.

What is the most efficient way to do this in `C#`? The collections do not have to be arrays nor the items bytes (although collection types that accept bytes would be appreciated).

Comment: Your code looks OK from the point of efficiency. Do you find something wrong with it (except `i != 255` in `for` loop)?

Comment: Not really. i was just wandering if .NET could offer something better, i suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to make a more efficent way by using pointers:

```
unsafe {
  fixed (byte* red = Red, green = Green, blue = Blue, pa = PA2) {
    byte* r = red, g = green, b = blue, p = pa;
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
      *p = *r; p++; r++;
      *p = *g; p++; g++;
      *p = *b; p++; b++;
    }
  }
}
```

In x86 mode this is about twice as fast, but in x64 mode there is no difference.

In conclusion, the code that you have is already fast enough for most applications. If you need it to be really fast you can optimise it a bit, but not much.

Answer (score 5):

I would try avoiding `3*i` multiplication:

```
byte[] Red = new byte[255];
byte[] Green = new byte[255];
byte[] Blue = new byte[255];
int newSize = Red.Length + Green.Length + Blue.Length;
byte[] PA = new byte[newSize];
for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i += 3)
{
    PA[i + 0] = Red[i];
    PA[i + 1] = Green[i];
    PA[i + 2] = Blue[i];
}
```

*Edit*

Or even something like that:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    PA[j++] = Red[i];
    PA[j++] = Green[i];
    PA[j++] = Blue[i];
}
```

*(Suggested by [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941240/wiktor-zychla))*

Comment: Sorry, that's was just leftover from the code i'm using right now (which needed it done that way for some other reasons).

Comment: @Default: nope but he probably needs two indexers then, one to fast forward through the target array and another to follow source arrays.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I removed my comment since I misread the logic. Interesting approach though. :)

Comment: By the way, just did some tests and my method still seems a bit faster, than the one with 2 integers.

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency is a thin decisional layer, but from the *performance* perspective, I would say that you already do it in efficient way.

```
//allocate immediately memory need, so more shrinking of memory will happen 
byte[] PA = new byte[Red.Length + Green.Length + Blue.Length]; 

//use for loop, that normally equals to foreach in some cases is faster
for (int i = 0; i != 255; ++i)
{
    PA[i + 0] = Red[i];
    PA[i + 1] = Green[i];
    PA[i + 2] = Blue[i];
}
```

Comment: Using != as a for loop guard was considered bad practice 20 years ago ;) I don't think it has changed from that time. Also, you can't just increment the index by one as your G and B would be overwritten by R in the next loop.

Comment: i heard using != was faster actually (feel free to correct me if i'm wrong, please)...

Comment: @StefanDenchev: for in some measurements results in faster iteration, then foreach.

Comment: @StefanDenchev for types such as `int`, the `<` and `!=` operators shouldn't make a noticable difference. Use the one that is most readable / less error prone.