# Most efficient way to merge sorted collections into a new sorted collection?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, scala, sorting, merge

I have to merge into a single sorted collection various collections that are already sorted. This operation needs to be done for not very large collections (around 5 elements) and with not many sources (maybe about 10), but the output should be calculated fast (non-blocking server).

In the case of two source collections it's pretty trivial, but when the number of source collections increases, there are different strategies to consider (`n` source collections, each with `m` elements):

- Concatenate, then sort. It has `O(n*m*log(n*m))` complexity (quicksorting `n*m` elements).
- Scan all heads, select the lowest, push it to the destination collection. I guess that it has `O(n*n*m)` complexity (scan `n` heads `n*m` times, that is the total number of elements).
- Merging collections in pairs until you have only one collection. I guess that it has `O(n*n*m)` complexity too (do `n` merging phases, each phase with at most `n*m` elements).
- Keep the collections in a min-heap (using the head as the key), removing the min and re-adding the collection with the next head in every step. I guess that this has `O(log(n)*n*m)` (the heap remove and insert operations are `log(n)` and they are done `n*m` times).

So, the computational complexity (if I haven't made any mistakes) of the sophisticated heap-based selection of the min element every time seems to be the best. Memory-wise the heap might be more garbage-collector friendly, as it doesn't need as many intermediate temporary collections.

Have I missed something (mistakes calculating the complexities or missed any alternative way to do it)? My implementation is most likely to be done in Javascript or maybe Scala, so any runtime concerns that might apply to those execution environments are welcome!

BTW this is **not** related: [Most efficient way to merge collections preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494225/most-efficient-way-to-merge-collections-preserving-order)

Comment: 50 elements? Are you serious? Even insertion sort with handle that kind of scale with ease (and might well be the fastest option).

Comment: I know the size is stupidly small, but if I have to handle lots of those requests per second, every little helps...

Comment: And the question is still valid for larger inputs, it might be helpful for somebody else :)

Comment: Well maybe, but a correct answer to the question with larger input is totally different from a correct answer to the question with only 50 elements of input. I think "one" is generally a reasonable amount of different questions per question :)

Comment: Now let me reiterate something here. Maybe I didn't get your question right. Do you have a *large* sorted collection into which you want to insert a small number of small, sorted runs of items? Because then my answer is more or less irrelevant. I guess my earlier interpretation is correct, but "merge into a single sorted collection various collections" is not entirely unambiguous

Comment: I don't have an existing collection, I just want to merge the different sorted runs into a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Since your data set is so small, your asymptotic considerations are pretty much irrelevant (although correct) because the much more important factor will be micro-optimization. I would suggest you to compare at least the following options, in increasing order of effort needed to implement them:

- Concatenate and just use the built-in sort algorithm. This is good because it is likely to be very fast for short arrays and because in the case of Javascript, it is written in the host language and likely to be much faster than any given pure JS solution (even with JIT compilation)
- Concatenate and use insertion sort. It is `O(k)` in the number of descents. For 5 lists of size 10 each, the worst case for `k` is 1000. But in reality it will be much less. You could probably even prevent the worst case, for example by presorting the lists in order of increasing first element or just randomizing the order.
- Part the sources into two groups, concatenate each and sort them using insertion sort (for 25 elements insertion sort is likely to be the overall fastest comparison sort) and then merge the results.
- for 10 sources, merge them in a binary-tree fashion (merge 1 with 2, 3 with 4 etc. and then repeat for the resulting lists of size 20). Essentially this is just the second phase of merge sort

These are general suggestions. Depending on your data set, there is likely to be a customly tailored option that is even better. For example, use counting sort if the input are small enough numbers. Maybe use radix sort for larger numbers, but that's probably not going to give you a lot of speed over insertion sort. If you have any pattern in the input, exploit it.

Comment: Having advantage of individual collections are sorted ,Cant we just use the Merge Sort ?

Comment: @Mani: Sure, if you look closely, that is one of my options as well (the last bullet point). I doubt it will be faster than other options however

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Merge.

**Full version**

There's nothing like testing.

Let's suppose your underlying collection is a `List`.  We'll store them in an `Array`.

```
val test = Array(
  List("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon"),
  List("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"),
  List("baby", "child", "adult", "senior"),
  List("red", "yellow", "green"),
  List("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"),
  List("tabby", "siamese", "manx", "persian"),
  List("collie", "boxer", "bulldog", "rottweiler", "poodle", "terrier"),
  List("budgie", "cockatiel", "macaw", "galah", "cockatoo"),
  List("Alabama", "California", "Georgia", "Maine", "Texas", "Vermont", "Wyoming"),
  List("I", "have", "to", "merge", "into")
).map(_.sorted)
```

Then your initial idea might be to just flatten and sort.

```
scala> val ans = th.pbench{ test.flatten.sorted.toList }
Benchmark (20460 calls in 183.2 ms)
  Time:    8.246 us   95% CI 8.141 us - 8.351 us   (n=18)
  Garbage: 390.6 ns   (n=1 sweeps measured)
ans: List[String] = List(Alabama, California, Georgia, I, Maine, ...)
```

Or you might implement a custom flatten-and-sort:

```
def flat(ss: Array[List[String]], i0: Int, i1: Int): Array[String] = {
  var n = 0
  var i = i0
  while (i < i1) {
    n += ss(i).length
    i += 1
  }
  val a = new Array[String](n)
  var j = 0
  i = i0
  while (i < i1) {
    var s = ss(i)
    while (s ne Nil) {
      a(j) = s.head
      j += 1
      s = s.tail
    }
    i += 1
  }
  a
}

def mrg(ss: Array[List[String]]): List[String] = {
  val a = flat(ss, 0, ss.length)
  java.util.Arrays.sort(a, new java.util.Comparator[String]{
    def compare(x: String, y: String) = x.compare(y)
  })
  a.toList
}

scala> val ans = th.pbench{ mrg(test) }
Benchmark (20460 calls in 151.7 ms)
  Time:    6.883 us   95% CI 6.850 us - 6.915 us   (n=18)
  Garbage: 293.0 ns   (n=1 sweeps measured)
ans: List[String] = List(Alabama, California, Georgia, I, Maine, ...)
```

Or a custom pairwise merge

```
def mer(s1: List[String], s2: List[String]): List[String] = {
  var s3 = List.newBuilder[String]
  var i1 = s1
  var i2 = s2
  while (true) {
    if (i2.head < i1.head) {
      s3 += i2.head
      i2 = i2.tail
      if (i2 eq Nil) {
        do {
          s3 += i1.head
          i1 = i1.tail
        } while (i1 ne Nil)
        return s3.result
      }
    }
    else {
      s3 += i1.head
      i1 = i1.tail
      if (i1 eq Nil) {
        do {
          s3 += i2.head
          i2 = i2.tail
        } while (i2 ne Nil)
        return s3.result
      }
    }
  }
  Nil  // Should never get here
}
```

followed by a divide-and-conquer strategy

```
def mge(ss: Array[List[String]]): List[String] = {
  var n = ss.length
  val a = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(ss, ss.length)
  while (n > 1) {
    var i,j = 0
    while (i < n) {
      a(j) = if (i+1 < n) mer(a(i), a(i+1)) else a(i)
      i += 2
      j += 1
    }
    n = j
  }
  a(0)
}
```

and then you see

```
scala> val ans = th.pbench{ mge(test) }
Benchmark (40940 calls in 141.1 ms)
  Time:    2.806 us   95% CI 2.731 us - 2.882 us   (n=19)
  Garbage: 146.5 ns   (n=1 sweeps measured)
ans: List[String] = List(Alabama, California, Georgia, I, Maine, ...)
```

So, there you go.  For data of the size you indicated, and for using lists (which merge very cleanly), a good bet is indeed divide-and-conquer merges.  (Heaps probably won't be any better and may be worse because of the additional complexity of maintaining a heap; heapsort tends to be slower than mergesort for the same reason.)

(Note: `th.pbench` is a call to my microbenchmarking utility, `Thyme`.)

---

Some additional suggestions involve an insertion sort:

```
def inst(xs: Array[String]): Array[String] = {
  var i = 1
  while (i < xs.length) {
    val x = xs(i)
    var j = i
    while (j > 0 && xs(j-1) > x) {
      xs(j) = xs(j-1)
      j -= 1
    }
    xs(j) = x
    i += 1
  }
  xs
}
```

But these are not competitive with the merge sort either with one sweep:

```
scala> val ans = th.pbench( inst(flat(test, 0, test.length)).toList )
Benchmark (20460 calls in 139.2 ms)
  Time:    6.601 us   95% CI 6.414 us - 6.788 us   (n=19)
  Garbage: 293.0 ns   (n=1 sweeps measured)
ans: List[String] = List(Alabama, California, Georgia, I, Maine, ...)
```

or two:

```
scala> th.pbench( mer(inst(flat(test, 0, test.length/2)).toList,
                      inst(flat(test, test.length/2,test.length)).toList) )
Benchmark (20460 calls in 119.3 ms)
  Time:    5.407 us   95% CI 5.244 us - 5.570 us   (n=20)
  Garbage: 390.6 ns   (n=1 sweeps measured)
res25: List[String] = List(Alabama, California, Georgia, I, Maine,
```

Comment: To actually come to the conclusion that this is a good approach you would have to compare it against other options, or am I missing something? I'm pretty sure for example that doing insertion sort of lists of size 25 and then doing a single merge is pretty darn fast

Comment: @NiklasB. - Quicksort already does insertion sort on small arrays, so that's more-or-less ruled out.  (Insertion sort on immutable lists is painful.)  "Best bet" is maybe a bit too decisive of wording, however.

Comment: Quicksort probably does at least one partitioning step before falling back to insertion sort. The single partitioning is potentially more costly than the single merge, so we don't really know :) OP will have to benchmark a lot if he wants a definite answer on that

Comment: +1. Note that a k-way merge with a heap can be a much better choice because it only looks at each item once, and because the temporary memory requirements are much smaller. Pairwise merging requires O(n) extra space and O(k) scans of the entire data set. That's especially expensive when the data is larger than will fit in memory. But, with the small data sets the OP is talking about ... pretty much anything will work.

Comment: @JimMischel - Pairwise merging requires `O(log k)` scans if you do it recursively.  Folding the merge is a silly thing to do, but that would be `O(k)`.  And heaps require `O(log k)` work on key deletion, which is what you need to do each time you remove an element.  It's the same order of complexity overall, and the constant factor is generally worse since either you use something with two `log k` steps (insert/delete on a binary heap) or you have more complex data structures to work with (e.g. Fibonacci heap).